# how to calculate the number of times a word appears is in a phrase

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create a code in which I have to count the number of times a word appears inside a sentence, but after a lot of searching and searching about, I can only find codes that use the `fgets` function, I wanted to know if you would know for which other thing, I could replace the `fgets` and still work the whole thing.

This is the code I've developed for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    char phrase[250];
    char word[50], c;
    int count;
    int a;

    count = 0;

    printf("Type a phrase: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", &phrase);
    printf("Type a word: ");
    scanf("%s", &word);

    for (a = 0; word[a] != '\0'; a++) {
        if (word[a] == c)
            count++;

    }

    if (count == 0) {
        printf("word not found in the sentence");
    }
    else {
        printf("Count: = %d\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Besides everything, I believe that I am accomplishing something wrong in the for , but I can't understand. If you can help me understand my mistake, and what else besides the `fgets` could be used, I'd love to.

Comment: `if(word[a]== word )` this comparison makes no sense (and should at least produce a compiler warning)

Comment: you are not handling with words , at most with one word and there is no relation between word and fgets, read more about [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: `if(word[a]== word )` this is meaningless. You are checking if character at position `a` is equal to pointer to an array.

Comment: `other` is _not_ valid syntax (I've replaced this with `else`). And, you need a `;` on the end of your `char` definition.

Comment: Note that the test `if (word[a] == c)` uses `char c` that is never assigned a value, so this test will have unpredictable results.

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand your `for` loop and `if` statement.
I did not test this code. But its logic may helps:

```
int j = 0;
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (word[j] = phrase[i])
    {
        j += 1;
        if (word[j] == '\0')
        {
            counter += 1;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` is the proper way to read a sentence, just learn to use it.

Read the sentence and the word. And declare a pointer to char.

Assign to the pointer the result of `strstr(sentence,word)`  and increment the variable `count` which you need to initialize to 0.

Keep doing `strstr(pointer,word)` till you reach the end of the sentence.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/